# How to fix an error while installing XAMPP on Windows, when Apache is not working and UAC cannot be deactivated?"

Tags: performance, error-handling, makegood

Everytime i start the pache in xampp it's not running and there was an error like blockport.

I tried to reinstall the xampp, turn off the firewall, change UAC and restart pc but all of this is not resolving the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.